# Select box and input

Tags: php, html, ajax, input, drop-down-menu

I have a select box and a numeric input. The two are interrelated so that selecting an option changes the maximum and minimum numerical input values For example, if Iran is selected, it will be a 30 min and a max 300, and...

See my tables in the database:

[image]

[image]

Also my codes:

```
  <select name="selbox" id="selbox"selected="selected">

            <label for="selbox">please select country</label>

            <option style="display: none;">country</option>
            <?php
include_once 'config.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM countreis";
$result = $con->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['countries_name'].'</option>';
    } 
    }else{
       echo'<option >not found</option>';          
    }

?>
        </select>
        <input type="number" name="sel-number" id="sel-number"min=""max="">
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $("#selbox").on("change",function(){

        var selboxId = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            type:"POST",
            cache:false,
            data:{selboxId:selboxId},
            success:function(data){
                $("#sel-number").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How can I make changes to Min and Max Input when the option is selected?

Comment: Have you tried assigning the values to `.min` and `.max` directly? What format does `data` have?

Comment: Yes from database

Comment: Not the source, but format. Do you send it as JSON? Is it an array? An object? A plain string?

Comment: Show the code of action.php, please